# Can gRPC method return a message with a field that could be string or null?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-go

I'm designing a gRPC service written in Go.

In front of the gRPC service is Envoy which converts incoming HTTP requests to gRPC and converts the gRPC responses to JSON.

The requirement of this application is to have an endpoint that returns the following JSON object:

```
{
    my_id: "AAA"
}
```

I can model this response pretty simply in Go like this:

```
// A MyResponse object.
message MyResponse {
  // contents is a list of contents.
  string my_id = 1;
}
```

But the requirement that I have is that sometimes my_id might be null. In that case, I want to get the following JSON back:

```
{
    my_id: null
}
```

it

Is it possible to modify `MyResponse` such that `my_id` can be a string or a null in the JSON object that is returned? If so, how? If not, isn't this a pretty big gap in the design of gRPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the [StringValue](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.StringValue) field of the Package `google.protobuf`:

> StringValue Wrapper message for string.
>
> The JSON representation for StringValue is JSON string.

So in your proto files, you should import:

```
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
```

then use as example:

```
  google.protobuf.StringValue name = 2;
```

For handle the values you can check the `wrappers.StringValue`
type of the [github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/wrappers](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/wrappers) package and the helpers of the [google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/wrapperspb](http://google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/wrapperspb) repo.

Comment: Can `StringValue` return a null? Why is `StringValue` better than `string`? I don't think you answered my question.

Comment: Hi @SaqibAli The scope of this field is to allow null values, please made a try... Further reading https://itnext.io/protobuf-and-null-support-1908a15311b6 and https://tomasbasham.dev/development/2017/09/13/protocol-buffers-and-optional-values.html